# Fanuc Adapter Issues

Tags: cnc

I am trying to use the Fanuc Adapter found here https://github.com/mtconnect/adapter . And I've gotten this to compile and run on a machine with a Fanuc Controller. My problem is that it is giving me a result of -16 anytime I make a connection to it with an agent or through a web browser. I think the problem is that the machine is using an HSSB connection instead of ethernet and I have the wrong IP and Port. Yet everything online points to setting the IP to 127.0.0.1 and the default port to 8193, which I have tried. Does anyone know what could be the issue or how to set up a Fanuc Adapter on a controller with an HSSB connection? All the resources I've found only explain connecting via ethernet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The adapter was always using a ethernet handle. Changed the source code to check and use both.